# Is there any documentation about MSKLC .klc file format?

Tags: parsing, keyboard

I need to parse .klc files from msklc and I can't find any docs about it's format.
I know this format is simple, but I have some misunderstanding.  So where I can find information about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found some code in the keyboard layout tool, which might help you. I have pasted it [Here](http://pastebin.com/UXc1ub4V). I extracteded it from the exe using il-spy.

Apparently the code parses the klc file for you.

I have not tested it out, but it could serve as a starting point.

Comment: This is the best kind of documentation there might be for this format, given how the parser is written. Great answer!